# How can I extend te MembershipUser class w/o multiple inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, asp.net-membership

At the top level I have a Person class. Next I want .NET's MembershipUser class to inherit from it, because a member is a person. However I want to extend the MembershipUser class which means, I think, I need to create my OWN MembershipUser class which inherits from MembershipUser and then adds my own properties. But once I do that, I can no longer inherit from Person due to multiple inheritance rules (ASP.NET 2.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating an interface, `IPerson` and replacing your concrete `Person` class with a class which inherits from `MembershipUser` and implements `IPerson`.

You could also keep your concrete `Person`, create `IPerson` and have your own class encapsulate a `Person` instance and inherit from `MembershipUser` while implementing `IPerson`.

In either case, anywhere where you once used a concrete `Person` type you should replace with `IPerson` (such as method arguments).

```
interface IPerson
{
    string LastName { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class MyMembershipUser : MembershipUser, IPerson
{
    private Person _person = new Person();

    // constructors, etc.

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _person.LastName; }
        set { _person.LastName = value; }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could continue using Person and have it encapsulate a MembershipUser instance (as part of a constructor) and include an explicit cast for Person to MembershipUser when needed...

```
class Person
{
    private readonly MembershipUser _mu;
    public Person(MembershipUser mu)
    {
        _mu = mu;
    }

    public static explicit operator MembershipUser(Person p)
    {
        // todo null check
        return p._mu;
    }
}

// example
var person = new Person(Membership.GetUser("user"));
Membership.UpdateUser((MembershipUser)person);
```

I would go with the interface implementation solution myself.